# cannot locate -lpaho-mqttpp3 when attempting to compile paho mqtt cpp samples

Tags: makefile, centos, ld, mqtt, paho

As per title I'm having problems running the Makefile located in
org.ecliplse.paho.mqtt.cpp/src/samples

I understand the C++ library requires the C library to be correctly installed. To do so I followed the documentation
and in /usr/local/lib I'm able to locate

```
libpaho-mqtt3a.so
libpaho-mqtt3a.so.1
libpaho-mqtt3a.so.1.0
libpaho-mqtt3as.so
libpaho-mqtt3as.so.1
libpaho-mqtt3as.so.1.0
libpaho-mqtt3c.so
libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1
libpaho-mqtt3c.so.1.0
libpaho-mqtt3cs.so
libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1
libpaho-mqtt3cs.so.1.0
```

am I missing something on the installation of the C library? should lpaho-mqttpp3 be produced at that stage?

please help

Comment: Did you copy the files to /usr/local/lib manually?

Comment: Also have you installed the cpp library as well yet?

Comment: Is your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` looking in `/usr/local/lib`?

Comment: hadn't copied the files manually but the install of the Paho C library placed them there. cross checked the directories listed in the Makefile when attempting to install the cpp library.

Answer (score 0):

Received this answer from [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mqtt/gux1BxfSBUU)

> Yes, apologies, we're currently working on the build system for the C++ library.  All the libraries that you see in the /usr/local/lib are the Paho C libraries.  The C++ library produces a single library, libpaho-mqttpp, when you build from the top-level cpp workspace. That's the file that is missing.
>
> The GitHub 'develop' branch is in flux at the moment, as we proceed to a 1.0 release of the C++ library, but has a number of updates that might be helpful, particularly a "make install" build target. To get this, clone the latest GitHub repo and then checkout the 'develop' branch:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp.git
$ cd paho.mqtt.cpp
$ git checkout develop

$ make
$ sudo make install
$ make samples
```

> That get you going for now. Look for a stable 'master' in a few weeks time.
>
> Frank Pagliughi